# NotFoundError when restore tensorflow model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to save model and restore in other file using tensorflow. I use this code for train and save model.

```
import input_data
import os
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

# train data and get results for batches
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
# train the data
for i in range(10):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
print(batch_xs)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print ("accuracy", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
arr=prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images}, session=sess)

#print ("predictions", )
#for i in range(len(arr)):
    #print(arr[i])

save_path = saver.save(sess, '/model.ckpt')
print ('Model saved in file: ', save_path)
```

and try to restore using this code.

```
import input_data
import os
import tensorflow as tf
#mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
tf.train.NewCheckpointReader("./model.ckpt")
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        #print("sess.run")
        saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
        print ("Model restored.")
```

In `saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")` line I have a NotFoundError. The error look like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1020     try:
-> 1021       return fn(*args)
   1022     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1002                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1003                                  status, run_metadata)
   1004 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    468           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 469           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    470   finally:

NotFoundError: Key y_3 not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_16/RestoreV2_47 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_16/Const_0, save_16/RestoreV2_47/tensor_names, save_16/RestoreV2_47/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-17503962c118> in <module>()
     17         sess.run(init_op)
     18         #print("sess.run")
---> 19         saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
     20         print ("Model restored.")

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1386       return
   1387     sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
-> 1388              {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
   1389 
   1390   @staticmethod

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    764     try:
    765       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 766                          run_metadata_ptr)
    767       if run_metadata:
    768         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    962     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    963       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 964                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    965     else:
    966       results = []

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1012     if handle is None:
   1013       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1014                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1015     else:
   1016       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1032         except KeyError:
   1033           pass
-> 1034       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1035 
   1036   def _extend_graph(self):

NotFoundError: Key y_3 not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_16/RestoreV2_47 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_16/Const_0, save_16/RestoreV2_47/tensor_names, save_16/RestoreV2_47/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save_16/RestoreV2_47', defined at:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-42-17503962c118>", line 14, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1000, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1030, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 624, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 361, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 200, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 441, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key y_3 not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_16/RestoreV2_47 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_16/Const_0, save_16/RestoreV2_47/tensor_names, save_16/RestoreV2_47/shape_and_slices)]]
```

What is the real problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are saving in your "/" directory and loading from "./".

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should give the tf.Variable w and b a name. For example,
`W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]),name="w_var")`
`b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]),name="b_var")`
Good luck to you!

Comment: Giving a name to variables in TensorFlow isn't necessary (apart from that this does not answer the question).